# How to aggregate all columns into array in SQL when using group-by?

Tags: sql, select, aggregate, amazon-athena

Given a table like:

| item | vietnamese | cost | unique_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fruits | trai cay | 10 | abc123 |
| fruits | trai cay | 8 | foo99 |
| fruits | trai cay | 9 | foo99 |
| fruits | trai cay | 12 | abc123 |
| fruits | trai cay | 14 | abc123 |
| vege | rau | 3 | rr1239 |
| vege | rau | 3 | rr1239 |

Usually when it's not group by I can do:

```
SELECT * from mytable
```

But if I had use group by to group the rows with the same item name, I can't directly do:

```
SELECT 
item, 
array_agg(vietnamese) as vietnamese
array_agg(cost) as cost
array_agg(unique_id) as unique_id
from mytable
GROUP BY item
```

**Is there an option to automatically all columns in SQL `array_agg(*)`?**

Comment: no, there is not.

Comment: Please update your question with the result you want to achieve from your sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no syntax to do what you describe. E.g. `COUNT(*)` does not mean `COUNT(a), COUNT(b), COUNT(c), …`, the star in that context does not refer to an expansion of columns.

In general, SQL is pretty bad at meta-programming, i.e. using runtime information to modify queries. You can't select columns that all start with "a", or tables that match a pattern. SQL is very static, with a few exceptions, like `SELECT *`.